# How to get address bar parameters from URLs of this form with php?

Tags: php

I saw a forum (IPS) with the following URL scheme:

```
www.example.com/index.php?/topic/12345
```

Which displays the topic ID 12345.

I am pretty new to php, and I was wondering, what exactly do they do to understand that the above request is asking for the topic ID 12345? I only know how to gather info with `$_POST` and `$_GET`. Here is my attempt with the latter:

```
echo "The user wants to see the topic ID " . $_GET["topic"];
```

But this requires an URL of the form

```
www.example.com/index.php?topic=12345
```

So, what did they do to achieve that scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You can use url-rewriting to rewrite the url on the web-server to a url with query variables (you can find a lot about url-rewriting here on SO);
2. You can analyze a server variable like `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to split and analyze the url in your php script. You would still need rewriting to make sure all requests pass through your script and don't go to a not-found page.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably using something similar to an apache module named `mod_rewrite`. `mod_rewrite` is used to rewrite URLs. In this case ?topic=12345 is being rewritten/translated as topic/12345/.

There's a decent article over at [branded3.com](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/) which outlines some cool stuff you can do with `mod_rewrite`. You'll need the `Create beautiful url’s with mod_rewrite` section to see how it is used to create nicer looking URLs.